# Unexpected Date result from using Number and Split

Tags: javascript

Why does the following code:

```
    newDate = "2-24-2014";
    var splitDate = newDate.split('-');
    var dateObj = new Date(Number(splitDate[0]), Number(splitDate[1]) - 1, Number(splitDate[2]));
```

Produce the following?:

```
Sat Jun 05 1909 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

I know the formatting but not the strange date itself. I was wondering if it had something to do with Number but cant seem to find any answers on this.

Comment: Year should come first : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.

Comment: @wared `splitDate.unshift() - 1` will face parsing error.  so change it to `+(splitDate.unshift()) - 1`

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Praveen. I've checked before posting of course and it works with Chrome, maybe not in some other browsers. Let us know :)

Comment: @Praveen, What would the differences be between your suggestion above and new Date(Date.parse("2-24-2014"))? Both work but would like to know more! Thanks.

Comment: You can get a good explanation from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2587398/1671639) also `new Date(Date.parse("2-24-2014"))` won't work in FF think so. In my aboe suggest you are parsing to string where `-` operation can't be performed for `string` dataType.  Hence I mentioned it.

Comment: Indeed, `'1'+1` gives `"11"` while `'1'-1` gives `0`, I guess it might vary across implementations(?).

Comment: @wared Seems weird.  Here in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vKNYy/6/) I checked the typeof the both `splitDate.pop()` => returns `string` whereas `splitDate.unshift()` => returns `number`.  So auto data conversion is taking place with unshift think so

Comment: @Praveen Well done! Indeed, `unshift` returns the length of the array : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift. Actually, I've confused `shift` and `unshift`... My bad :/

Comment: @Praveen Anyway, the following fixed code - I've removed the infected comment :) - `new Date(splitDate.pop(), splitDate.shift() - 1, splitDate.pop())` works with an implicit conversion. I guess the `-` operator doesn't allow string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Date(Year, Month, Date)
```

The above is the actual format.  Whereas you have given like `new Date(Month, Date, Year)`

```
var dateObj = new Date(Number(splitDate[2]), Number(splitDate[0]) - 1, Number(splitDate[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the order of parameters:

```
new Date(Number(splitDate[2]), Number(splitDate[0]) - 1, Number(splitDate[1]));
```

or simply do this:

```
new Date(Date.parse("2-24-2014"))
```

Comment: **FYI:** Possible that `new Date(Date.parse("2-24-2014"))` will not work in FF check http://jsfiddle.net/vKNYy/7/ in FF

Comment: @Praveen: thanks for pointing out, but I just tried it in FF and it worked. which version of FF do you use?

Comment: I'm using latest version of FF.  I think this morning an auto update took place.